# How do I log into a file if log4j failed to log into database?

Tags: java, log4j

There is a requirement of Audit logs into database. So I have following log4j setup which is logging into the database.This Audit log contains vital information therefore if somehow the application fails to log into database then it should log into a file (only failed data). Even it is a rare scenario, I must store failed logging messages into a file.

```
# Define the DB appender
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender

# Set JDBC URL
log4j.appender.DB.URL=url

# Set Database Driver
log4j.appender.DB.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

# Set database user name and password
log4j.appender.DB.user=pwd
log4j.appender.DB.password=user

# Set the SQL statement to be executed.
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO audit_log(loglevel, logger, message) VALUES('%p', '%C{1}:%L','%m%n')

# Define the layout for db appender
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

I have created another file appender which could log such scenarios but how do I know the database logging failed? All logging functions are void (info,error,warn,fatal), so there is no callback to know database log failed. Does anyone came across such scenario and found a solution or get around to achieve this. OR other logging mechanism for this scenario which allows logging into database and file.

```
log4j.appender.failedToLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.failedToLog.File=./logs/failedToLog/failedToAuditLog.log
log4j.appender.failedToLog.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.failedToLog.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.failedToLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.failedToLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z}] - [%C{1}:%L] - %m%n


log4j.category.failedAuditLogger=DEBUG, failedToLog
log4j.additivity.failedAuditLogger=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check code here

```
org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender#flushBuffer
```

If sql exception was thrown it will be handled by errorHandler. By default it is OnlyOnceErrorHandler, which will print error to strerr ( but only first time).
There is another implementation of error handling : FallbackErrorHandler. 
You can find how to configure error handler.

Comment: Thank you @commit-man, your answer exactly meets my requirements. I appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

> if somehow the application fails to log into database then it should log into a file (only failed data)

Use a [FailoverAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FailoverAppender), which wraps multiple appenders that are called in order, only calling the backup appender(s) if the primary fail(s).

Comment: Thank you @copeg for your response it does answers my question, however FailoverAppender is part of log4j2 and I am using log4j 1.2.17 version. :-)